# Firebase: Firestore, type error when creating a document in a nested collection

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

When submitting the form containing data about a property, I get the following error: `FirebaseError: Expected type 'za', but it was: a custom Ha object`. I couldn't find any resources online that explain what a Ha object is, nor could I find any info about type za. I believe it has something to do with the way I am accessing the nested collection but I have tried a few ways and have gotten the same response. I will put my code below with data types for all variables.

```js
const submitProperty = async () => {
  setLoading(true);
  const ref = collection(db, "users", user.uid, "properties");
  await setDoc(ref, {
    propertyName: propertyName, //string
    address: address, //string
    city: city, //string
    zipcode: zipcode, //string
    mortgage: mortgage, //number
    rentalIncome: rentalIncome, //number
    vacancy: vacancy, //bool
    propertyTax: propertyTax, //number
  });
  setLoading(false);
};
```

I tried changing data types: No change in response.
Changing the way I accessed the collection and created the document also yielded no change in response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ref` refers to a collection, so you can't call `setDoc` on it.

Are you looking to add a document to the collection? If so, use `addDoc` instead of `setDoc`.